# Hibernate NullPointerException while saving many to one related object

Tags: hibernate, one-to-many, many-to-one

I have these two entity.

```
@Entity
public class Stammdaten {
    @Id
    @Column(nullable = false)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "stammdaten" )
    private List<Address> addresses;

}

@Entity
public class Address {
    @Id
    @Column(nullable = false)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "stammdaten_id")
    private Stammdaten stammdaten;

}
```

I am trying save them as bidirection one to many relation. So I do this

```
public void create(){    
        stammdaten.getAddresses().add(homeAddress);
        stammdaten.getAddresses().add(semesterAddress);
        homeAddress.setStammdaten(stammdaten);
        semesterAddress.setStammdaten(stammdaten);

        addressService.save(homeAddress);
        addressService.save(semesterAddress);

        stammdatenService.save(stammdaten);
        }
```

But this give me error `java.lang.NullPointerException: null`. When I debug, all the objects `stammdaten`, `homeAddress` and `semesterAddress` are not null at all. I think there is some problem with configuring one to many and many to one relationship. But I could not figure it out. Please help.

Comment: I need more of that stacktrace. Where is the nullpointer happening?

Comment: If I change `private List<Address> addresses` to ` private List<Address> addresses = new ArrayList<Address>();`  then it works. But I don't understand why

Comment: Can you please update your code used for POJO. I want to check the getter & setters.

Answer (score 0):

addresses field are initialize null by default when class loaded by JVM. because you not initialize it and you access directly which case throws an null pointer exception. there is 3 solution for this problem(may be more).

initialize it when declaring e.g.   @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "stammdaten" ) private List addresses = new ArrayList<>(); common practice.

create default constructor and initialize inside it. bad practice because tight coupling

create List address = new ArrayList<>() inside client program and pass reference using setter method of that class. good practice.